# How to sum every other number in a file?

Tags: python, file, math

I need to create a sum of every other number in a file which looks like this:

```
10
20
30
40
```

and it would only add together 20 and 40 together to get 60.

```
try:
    infile = open("numbers.txt", "r")

    for lines in infile:
        print(sum(infile))
        infile.readline()[::2]

    infile.close()

except ValueError:
    print("Couldn't Open File")
except IOError:
    print("File not found")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
try:
    with open("numbers.txt", "r") as infile:
        print(sum([int(line) for line in infile][1::2]))
except ValueError:
    print("Couldn't Open File")
except IOError:
    print("File not found")
```

First, it uses the `with` construct to safely handle the opening and closing of the file. Second, it uses a list comprehension to make a list of the items in the file. Third, it uses `int()` to convert the lines from text to integers. Fourth, it uses the slice `[1::2]` to use every other line, starting with the second (which has index `1`). Fifth, it uses `sum` to add those numbers.

Is that clear? If you do not like the list comprehension, this could be done with a regular loop. The main disadvantage of my approach is that it forms a list of all the items before using only half of them. Here is code that removes that list by using a generator, so it uses less memory, but at the cost of being more complicated.

```
try:
    with open("numbers.txt", "r") as infile:
        print(sum(int(line) for ndx, line in enumerate(infile) if ndx % 2))
except ValueError:
    print("Couldn't Open File")
except IOError:
    print("File not found")
```